# return key by value in dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, python-3.x, key

I am trying to return the key in a dictionary given a value

in this case if 'b' is in the dictionary, I want it to return the key at which 'b' is (i.e 2)

```
def find_key(input_dict, value):
    if value in input_dict.values():
        return UNKNOWN            #This is a placeholder
    else:
        return "None"

print(find_key({1:'a', 2:'b', 3:'c', 4:'d'}, 'b'))
```

The answer I want to get is the key 2, but I am unsure what to put in order to get the answer, any help would be much appreciated

Comment: Are you sure you have your keys->values mapped the right way round?

Comment: You may be stuck with it, but your data structure poorly fits your needs.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Return *first* matching key:

```
def find_key(input_dict, value):
    return next((k for k, v in input_dict.items() if v == value), None)
```

Return *all* matching keys as a set:

```
def find_key(input_dict, value):
    return {k for k, v in input_dict.items() if v == value}
```

Values in a dictionary are not necessarily unique. The first option returns `None` if there is no match, the second returns an empty set for that case.

Since the order of dictionaries is arbitrary (dependent on what keys were used and the insertion and deletion history), what is considered the 'first' key is arbitrary too.

Demo:

```
>>> def find_key(input_dict, value):
...     return next((k for k, v in input_dict.items() if v == value), None)
... 
>>> find_key({1:'a', 2:'b', 3:'c', 4:'d'}, 'b')
2
>>> find_key({1:'a', 2:'b', 3:'c', 4:'d'}, 'z') is None
True
>>> def find_key(input_dict, value):
...     return {k for k, v in input_dict.items() if v == value}
... 
>>> find_key({1:'a', 2:'b', 3:'c', 4:'d'}, 'b')
set([2])
>>> find_key({1:'a', 2:'b', 3:'c', 4:'d', 5:'b'}, 'b')
set([2, 5])
>>> find_key({1:'a', 2:'b', 3:'c', 4:'d'}, 'z')
set([])
```

Note that we need to loop over the values each time we need to search for matching keys. This is not the most efficient way to go about this, especially if you need to match values to keys often. In that case, create a reverse index:

```
from collections import defaultdict

values_to_keys = defaultdict(set)

for key, value in input_dict:
    values_to_keys[value].add(key)
```

Now you can ask for the set of keys directly in O(1) (constant) time:

```
keys = values_to_keys.get(value)
```

This uses sets; the dictionary has no ordering so either, sets make a little more sense here.

Comment: +1 - good point about using `defaultdict(set)` ;)

Answer (score 7):

Amend your function as such:

```
def find_key_for(input_dict, value):    
    for k, v in input_dict.items():
        if v == value:
            yield k
```

Then to get the first key (or `None` if not present)

```
print next(find_key_for(your_dict, 'b'), None)
```

To get all positions:

```
keys = list(find_key_for(your_dict, 'b'))
```

Or, to get 'n' many keys:

```
from itertools import islice
keys = list(islice(find_key_for(your_dict, 'b'), 5))
```

Note - the keys you get will be 'n' many in the order the dictionary is iterated.

**If you're doing this more often than not (and your values are hashable), then you may wish to transpose your dict**

```
from collections import defaultdict

dd = defaultdict(list)
for k, v in d.items():
    dd[v].append(k)

print dd['b']
```

Comment: Nice.  Also, if values are always unique this can be done without a `defaultdict`.  `rev_d = {v:k for k,v in d.iteritems()}`

Comment: In the part about transposing the dict, you might also want to add "and the values are *unique*" as well.  Otherwise you don't really get a full transpose.  But, nice answer.  +1